# What analysis tool I can use to identify the relation between points and areas

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, point-in-polygon, python-toolbox, aggregate-points

I want a binary result for each purple point in this map, i.e. whether in or out od the blue polygon areas?

In this case, one is in and the other is out. What analysis tool in ArcGIS Pro (also arcpy package) I can use for this purpose?

[image]

I try to use AggregatePoints_sfa as follows:

```
AggregatePoints_sfa('Point_Location','Areas','Result')
```

But an error was incurred:

```
OSError: The toolbox file https://analysis2.arcgis.com/arcgis;services/tasks;UseSSOIdentityIfPortalOwned was not found.
```

Not sure if it is something to do with my ArcGis PRO version which is 2.2.0.

Comment: Spatial Join https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm is the tool you want or Select by Location https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/select-features-by-location.htm if you don't want to create a new feature class.

Comment: @MichaelStimson Nice! just quickly check Select by Location and it works somehow to match my requirement. Will develop it into a better solution using arcpy and export an user-friendly output.